# Pass a time object to soapui and get exception

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui

I use SoapUI to mock a WCF service. There is an object.

```
CallBeginTime = {2/22/2013 8:22:54 AM}

Date: {2/22/2013 12:00:00 AM}
Day: 22
DayOfWeek: Friday
DayOfYear: 53
Hour: 8
Kind: Unspecified
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 22
Month: 2
Second: 54
Ticks: 634971181740000000
TimeOfDay: {08:22:54}
Year: 2013
```

What I passed it as

`<nsb:CallBeginTime>{2/22/2013 8:22:54 AM}</nsb:CallBeginTime>`

I got an exception

```
 <InnerException>
                    <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                    <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                    <Message>The string '{2/22/2013 8:22:54 AM}' is not a valid AllXsd value.</Message>
                    <StackTrace>at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
                    at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToDateTime(String value)</StackTrace>
                    <Type>System.FormatException</Type>
                 </InnerException>
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you need to use this format:

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS where T represents the start of the Time data

For example your example data would be:

2013-02-22T08:22:54

See XSD [date](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) datatype for more.

Comment: I have copypasted the example time about 100 times now, you deserve my upvote :)